# TypeError no implicit conversion of Spree::Order into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am getting an error like this when I update the spree from 4.1 to 4.2 at the time of order creation.

Order Flow

1. Add product into the cart
2. Checkout product
3. Address
4. Shiping method
5. Payment
6. order completed and mail generated and this error displaying on success page TypeError no implicit conversion of Spree::Order into Hash

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you follow this guide - https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/upgrades/four-dot-one-to-four-dot-two.html and update Spree Auth Devise as well?
2. Did you customize Spree email templates / mailer classes?

Could you paste a full stack trace of the error? That would help to resolve this :)

Comment: Yes I have followed this guide, Actually in my project this gem is exist  gem 'spree_multi_vendor', github: 'kosenkodmitriy/spree_multi_vendor', branch: 'master'
  when i removing this thing then  working  fine   in 4.2   should i have to update spree_multi_vendor gem also ?  and how can i update   i am not able to find any guide